# logging to file with twistd and python logging

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging, twisted

When I run my twisted application like this:

```
twistd --pidfile ./twistd.pid -l $HOME/logs/my_application.log -oy service.tac
```

I find that it does not log anything sent through the [python logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) system. I noticed that there is a "PythonLoggingObserver" in twisted, but that redirects twisted logs to the logging module.

I would like to figure out how I can get all logs (regardless of log module) to go to the log file specified with the "-l" command on twistd. I suspect my logs are being written to the daemon's stdout.

Here is how I initialize python logging in the .tac file:

```
import logging

LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG

logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL)
logging.basicConfig(level=LOG_LEVEL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a stream handler using `twisted.python.log.logfile`.  For example:

```
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> from logging import StreamHandler, getLogger
>>> from twisted.python.log import startLogging, logfile
>>> observer = startLogging(stdout, setStdout=False)
2015-05-02 06:34:39-0400 [-] Log opened.
>>> getLogger().addHandler(StreamHandler(stream=logfile))
>>> getLogger().log(100, "Hello")
2015-05-02 06:36:26-0400 [-] Hello
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. Note that it is also possible to configure this in basicConfig by setting "stream=StreamHandler(stream=logfile).stream".